# Test a Nested Class Method in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Is there a way to test for the existence of a class method being called from another class method?

```
class AnimalRecord < ApplicationRecord
  COLLAR_ID = AnimalCollar::ID
  belongs_to :animal
  serialize :json, JSON
  scope :collar_id, -> { for_collar(COLLAR_ID) }

  def self.current_record(animal)
    animal_info = AnimalRecord.collar_id.first
    calculate_nutrients(animal_info)
  end

  def self.calculate_nutrients(animal)
    code result
  end
end
```

I can test the `current_record` method from current_record. But what is the proper way to test the `calculate_nutrients` method?

I had this:

```
context "test record" do
  before do
    @animal = create(:animal... )
    @animal_record = create(:animal_record...)
  end

  it "calls #calculate_nutrients" do 
    expected_response = responseHere
    expect(AnimalRecord).to receive(:calculate_nutrients).and_return(expected_response)

    AnimalRecord.current_record(@animal)
  end
```

But I get an error that says this:

```
    expected: 1 time with any arguments
       received: 0 times with any arguments
```

Comment: You need to move your expectation above your action. Right now you are standing at a bus stop when the bus has already passed by. (The action has already been called before your are creating your expectation)

Comment: @engineersmnky I had a typo. Thank you

Comment: Does it work without `.and_return`? Just this `expect(AnimalRecord).to receive(:calculate_nutrients)`?

Comment: @ka8725 it needed the return to work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have do remove the line `expect(AnimalRecord).to receive(:event)` from the test example. Seems there is no such method defined on `AnimalRecord`, but you are trying to "expect" it.